# is hosted parse support Push Notification?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

is hosted parse server has push notification support?

I tried searching the docs but I found only [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki#push-notifications-alternative-services)

Can anyone provide information on the same that how to achieve it?

Comment: yes self-hosted parse-server does have push notification support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse-server recently added support for push notifications and I've implemented it in my own app last week, and it works great. You can find more about it here: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/parse-server/guide/#push-notifications-quick-start

Make sure you're running the latest version of parse-server.